# Transform a cardinality into a summation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, summation

I have $\ell$ sets $S_1,S_2,\ldots,S_\ell$ where each set $S_k$ contains $n$ elements. Let $x_{ik}=1$ if and only if element $i$ is chosen from set $S_k$.

How to transform the following cardinality into a summation depending on $x_{ik}$?

$$f(O_1,O_2,\ldots,O_\ell)=\left|\bigcup_{k=1}^\ell O_k\right|,$$
where $O_k$ is a subset of elements chosen from $S_k$.

I found it as:

$$f(\mathbf{x})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\prod_{k=1}^\ell x_{ik}.$$

Comment: Hello, the statement is not clear enough, $x_ik=1$ if and only if element $i$ is in $O_k$ ? Are the sets $S_1,\ldots, S_l$ disjoint ?

Comment: Yes, $x_{ik}=1$ iff $i\in O_k$. The sets $S_k$ are not disjoint.

Comment: When you say $i\in O_k$, does that mean that $E_k = \{1, \ldots, n\}$ for all $k$ ?

Comment: No. $S_k$ could be any subset of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Comment: But your statement says that $|S_k| = n$, so $S_k$ has to be equal to $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ no ?

Comment: But I can provide an answer now with your clarifications

Comment: $S_k$ is an $n$-element set, that's what I meant. For example, if $n=3$, $S_1=\{1,3,6\}$ and $S_2=\{2,3,6\}$.

Comment: Ok so $S_k$ can be any finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Ok, now you can check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we will calculate

$$g_i = \begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } i\in \displaystyle\bigcup_{k=1}^l O_k \\ 0 \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Notice that :
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{l} 1-x_{ik} = \begin{cases} 0 \text{ if } i\in \bigcup_{k=1}^{l}O_k\\ 1\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

So that :

$$ g_i = 1 - \prod_{k=1}^{l} (1-x_{ik})$$

Now, you can compute the desired function by summing the $g_i$'s :

$$ f(O_1, \ldots, O_l) = \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \left(1 - \prod_{k=1}^l (1- x_{ik})\right)$$

Notice that the previous sum is actually finite because $O_1\cup \ldots\cup O_l$ is finite.